# Where is net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit for CentOS 5?

Tags: centos5

I am trying to fix latest security bug by doing:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit=999999999
```

however this file is missing on CentOS 5, kernel 2.6.18-371.12.1.el5PAE

Where is `net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit` for CentOS 5?

Comment: What latest security bug is that?

Comment: https://joindiaspora.com/p/7699430

Comment: I have confirmation that old kernels in CentOS 4 and CentOS 5 are not vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter was introduced with RFC 5961 support in 3.6 kernel, so you probably are not concerned by this flaw; if you were, you would be able to read and write this parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Officially the 2.6.x kernels do not have the tcp_challenge_ack_limit sysctl flag. If CentOS/RedHat released a version of the kernel with this code backported in it, then you probably have to update to a newer kernel.

Simply put, if you can't find a sysctl 'file' (it's a virtual file pointing to a kernel setting), then your kernel doesn't have that setting.

Comment: I can confirm that RHEL6, running 2.6.x, is affected by this.  Can't speak for other 2.6.x distributions.

Comment: Yeah, redhat backports lots of things to older kernels. Perhaps OP has an update waiting for his kernel package